# Compile exe for Windows using Wine

Tags: pi-4, python-3

I'm trying to use Wine on my RP4 to compile a script as a Windows Executable. Unfortunately I'm not able to install Python 3 on Wine.
I could not find any guide on installing python in wine on a RP using google...
Can someone explain to me which steps I need to follow to make it happen?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you are asking about two unrelated problems in your post ... compiling an exe and installing python ... please remove references to one of them and post in another question

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware what Wine is?  It clearly states in its name that WINE Is Not an Emulator - all it does is link Windows calls to the Linux equivalents.

You need to look for a cross compiler for Python that generates Windows executables though Python traditionally does not compile all the way down to a native executable - it's more an interpretive language by default.

The simplest way of generating executable files is to use the py2exe program from [here](http://py2exe.org/). Getting this to run under Linux is possible but can generate invalid programs that just hang.

A better option is to use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) on Windows (it's not a cross compiler) and do you development on a Windows box.  This does help by sorting all the version issues you often get with Python on multiple machines at different versions.

Sorry this is not quite the answer you want but your are trying to do two things not normally done - cross compile to Windows from Arm and compile a language that is not normally compiled.

For years Windows has been the predominant development platform (even the iPod started on a PC in Windows) and as a Mac user it hurts to type that!